# page break in mpdf extension :Yii

Tags: yii, mpdf

I am using mpdf library to print data in my Yii project.Here I want to print single data in each page means i need to be able to break the page after every single record.How can i use page break to solve my problem?
My Controller code is:

```
$this->layout      = 'pdf';
    $model             = new Email();
    $dataProvider      = $model->search();
    $dataProvider->pagination = false; 
    $mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();
    $mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf('', 'A5');
    $mPDF1->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('_gridview', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider), true));
    $mPDF1->Output();
```

My View code:

```
 foreach($dataList as $val)
            { ?>
            Dear Project Manager/manager <br/>
            <?php
            echo $val['Manager'];
            ?> <br/>
            Subject : <?php echo $val['subject'];?> <br/>

            <?php echo $val['message'];?>
            <?php $i++; }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:
First you have to define a div and then add CSS for that div.

```
<style>  
.break { page-break-before: always; } 
</style>
```

and in your view you have to add a div like this:

```
foreach($dataList as $val)
        { ?>
        Dear Project Manager/manager <br/>
        <?php
        echo $val['Manager'];
        ?> <br/>
        Subject : <?php echo $val['subject'];?> <br/>

        <?php echo $val['message'];?>
        <div class="break"></div>
        <?php $i++; }?>
```

This should help you.

Comment: Ok your answer was helpful .Thank you.